# Why are there two build options in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

I've just taken over a workspace which has been built with codeblocks 12.11 on a Linux environment.  There are several projects in it.  It started failing compilations so I had a look and I found myself getting into a muddle with the build options.  I would set an option then find that it wasn't set or get a failure like using // for comments in C and find that C99 had already been chosen.  After a while I figured out why: there are two Build Options in Codeblocks:

1. right click on the project and select Build Options
2. right click on the project, select Properties and then click on Build Options...

The two seem to be completely independent and just end up clobbering each other.  I've now moved everything to the second option

1. Is this the right thing to do
2. When should you use Build Options and when should you use Properties/Build Options.
3. Why are there two completely independent ways of getting to the same dialog that don't seem to reflect each other.

Comment: Those are both the same set of options, there are just two ways of navigating to it. (Three really, as you can also get there from the Project menu).  Consider using a more recent release (e.g. 16.01) in case you are running into bugs in old versions.

Comment: Also, check that you have selected the same target in each case. The build options dialog has a target selection on the left, and you can set different options for each target as well as project-global options by selecting the topmost line. Also note the "Policy" dropdown which controls how the per-target options are applied to the global options.

Comment: I'll try 16.01.  Have to update my repository so that it picks up 16.01.  It seems to think that 12.11 is the latest.